# Why my code is not able to convert each item of list from string to integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on a problem due to a small portion of my code. I can't find why that portion of code is not working properly.

By debugging each portion of my code, I found which lines are causing unexpected results. I have written that lines below. I have defined the list here so that I do not have to copy my full code.

```
list1=["-7","-7","-6"]

for test in list1:

    test=int(test)

print( type( list1[0] ) )
```

I expected type to be `int` but output is coming as `str` instead.

Comment: You are not storing the converted `test` anywhere. It is lost in the next iteration.

Comment: Save your converted items to a list, perhaps `li.append(int(test))`

Comment: You did not the list entries You have created a test var which is int

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the **content** of the list:

```
list1=["-7","-7","-6"]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = int(list1[i])

print(type(list1[0]))
```

A more pythonic approach would be to use a comprehension to change it all at once:

```
list1 = [int(x) for x in list1]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert each item of a list to integer format :

```
list1=["-7","-7","-6"]
list1 = list(map(int, list1))
```

`list1` becomes `[-7, -7, -6]`.

Now `type(list1[0])` would be `<class 'int'>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about appending the transformed value:

```
list1 = ["-7","-7","-6"]
list2 = [] # store integers
for test in list1:
    test = int(test)
    list2.append(test) # store transformed values

print(type(list2[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but it will not come public as I have reputation less than 15.